# Renaming Django model field

Tags: django, migration

I'm trying to convert one of my model fields (units) from FloatField to an IntegerField.

My strategy is this:

1. Add '_units' field  (IntegerField)
2. Copy data from 'units' to '_units'
3. Remove 'units'
4. Rename '_units' as 'units'

Migrations for steps 1 - 3 run fine but at Step 4 I get an error when I run the tests:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: myapp_mymodel._units

For this step I made an empty migration then added to the operations;

```
migrations.RenameField('MyModel', '_units', 'units')
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is there any problem with `migrations.AlterField`?

Comment: Ah yes, much easier. Thanks

Comment: Made answer from my comment.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`migrations.AlterField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/migration-operations/#alterfield) it will do all 4 steps in one.

Comment: I didn't know about that. I have been doing the hard way for all these months. LOL. Living and learning... haha! Thanks.

Comment: @Ev. There are might be some problems if you are altering fields which are not convertable one to another. So read the documentation.

Comment: Yeah. After I saw your post I went and read the documentation. It might have some limitations on certain databases, but for me it will do.

Comment: How would that do all 4 steps in one?

Comment: @CsabaToth by calling `migrations.AlterField` this migration command does all 4 steps described in question as one. Read the docs, if you still have questions let me know