# rename unique field in django model and migrate

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.11

I had a model which looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.TextField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    # other fields
```

Then I realised after working further on what I am building, that it is quite important that the `username` field is slightly differently named, so made an alteration in that line:

```
    username_internal = models.TextField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

and ran `python manage.py makemigrations myapp`.

It asked me for a default value, but when I look at the .py migration it created, don't like what it has done:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.4 on 2018-11-14 10:49
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import django.contrib.auth.validators
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0002_user_internalid'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='user',
            name='username_internal',
            field=models.TextField(default=5, max_length=100, unique=True),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='username',
            field=models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username'),
        ),
    ]
```

It is trying to create a new field, I just want it to rename the existing field.

Am new to Django (using 1.11.4) Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I think @Max 's solution would have worked if the field in the original model had been called anything but 'username'. Am new to Django, but I think this has overwritten instead of just adding to Django's standard user model and let to some problems with renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to you subclassing `AbstractUser` it is always including the `username` field so isnt picking up the rename for the migrations. You will need to change your user model class to look something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    username_internal = models.TextField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    ...

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username_internal'

    ...

    # you will also need to the user manager `objects = UserManager()`
    # you may be able to import and use the existing user manager from `django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager` depending on your other fields.
```

A full example is available on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example.

You may need to re-implement permissions methods depending on your use case. See [PermissionsMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.16/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L212).

Comment: Thanks, I modified the migration and ran  `python manage.py migrate` it looked like it ran okay, but seems to have broken something, am trying to work out what..

Comment: I think you must be right given [this](https://gist.github.com/dhbradshaw/e2bdeb502b0d0d2acced) although maybe it should be "alter" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37942618/4288043). Maybe it's a peculiarity of using Django 1.11 (not my choice). Symptom is that new column 'username_internal' is created instead of a renaming! I think the problem is more likely that username 'TextField' had overridden Django's standard user 'Charfield'. I give up on renaming for now if it's going to be this difficult, rolled back to previous migration.

Comment: Oh yeah. I see why that would happen. Its because you are subclassing `AbstractUser` which always includes the `username` field. To change the name of the username field you have to create your user class slightly differently. They have an example in the Django docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hopefully that will point you in the correct direction this time ;P

Comment: Thanks, will test/adapt it once I finish the current thought and will hopefully be the end of it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. It is a slimmer user, 9 fields were removed in the migration, date_joined, first_name, groups, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_name and user_permissions, but have learned something about it, if I want any of those fields back one day will put them back in manually. [Two user classes explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514354/difference-between-abstractuser-and-abstractbaseuser-in-django)